# Limit of $f(\sin x)$ doesn't exist

Tags: limits

I was given the following question:

Let $f : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a function. Suppose that $f$ is not a constant function. Define the function $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by
$$g(x) = f(\sin x).$$
Prove that the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}g(x)$ doesn't exist.

Now, I do know that I need to start by assuming towards contradiction that the limit does exist. And I do understand that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\sin x$ doesn't exist, but I can't find a way to contradict this, by choosing the right $\epsilon$ and $x$, since I barely know anything about $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)=l$, for some $l\in\mathbb R$, nd that $f$ is *not* constant. Now, let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ be two distinct real numbers from the range of $f$. Then $a=f(\alpha)$ and  $b=f(\beta)$, for some $\alpha,\beta\in[-1,1]$ and, since $f(\alpha)\neq f(\beta)$, $\alpha\neq\beta$. But then, since we have $\sin(x)=\alpha$ for arbitrarily large values of $x$ and we have $\sin(x)=\beta$ for arbitrarily large values of $x$ too, if you take $\varepsilon$ small enough so that $(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$ doesn't contain both numbers $a$ and $b$, it is false that there is a $M>0$ such that$$x>M\implies f(x)\in(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon).$$But this is impossible, since we are assuming that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)=l$.

Comment: Do I need to choose the same value of x for both $\sin(x)=\alpha$ and $\sin(x)=\beta$? Because If so, there's no such number. But if not, then how can I contradict that $$f(x)\in(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$$ ?

Comment: Because $(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$ doesn't contain both $a$ and $b$. Suppose that $a\notin(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$. Then, since we have $\sin(x)=\alpha$ for arbitrarily large values of $x$, we have $f\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)=a$ for arbitrarily large values of $x$. Which is impossible if we assume that there is some $M>0$ such that$$x>M\implies f\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)\in(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon).$$

Comment: Alright, but in order to contradict this I need to use specific numbers and not show that in general. Does a and b need to be dependent of L? Because that's the only way to show that they are no in that range.

Comment: If $x,y\in(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$, then $|x-y|<2\varepsilon$. So, take $\varepsilon=\frac12|a-b|$ and then you will be sure that $a$ and $b$ cannot both belong to the interval.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b, f(a)$ is distinct of $f(b)$, $x=arcsin(a), y=arcsin(b)$

$x_n=arcsin(a)+2n\pi, y_n=y+2n\pi$, $g(x_n)=f(a), g(y_n)=f(b)$,

$lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n=lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}y_n=+\infty$ implies that $lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty}g(z)$ does not exist.

Comment: How do you explain that $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n=lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}y_n=+\infty$?

Comment: $lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a+bn=+\infty$ if $b>0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b\in[-1,1]$ be given such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Now, define that sequence

$$x_n=\arcsin(a)+2\pi n$$

$$y_n=\arcsin(b)+2\pi n$$

Clearly both these go to infinity. Then

$$f(\sin(x_n))=f(\sin(\arcsin(a)+2\pi n))=f(\sin(\arcsin(a)))=f(a)$$

$$f(\sin(y_n))=f(\sin(\arcsin(b)+2\pi n))=f(\sin(\arcsin(b)))=f(b)$$

If we assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ exists and is $L$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)=L$$

However

$$f(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(y_n)=f(b)$$

which is a contradiction. We conclude $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ does not exist.